# Check files for conventions

Tags: shell-script, files, utilities, character-encoding

I need a script that checks and lists all text files for project conventions. With conventions I mean for example:

- UTF-8 encoding
- No trailing white spaces
- Newline at the end of file
- No not-ascii chars
- LF for line endings

I do not want to reinvent the wheel. Maybe there is a tool doing this. Do you know some?

Comment: file -i or --mime

Comment: "Newline at the end of file": does that mean you want to be sure the implicit Unix newline is there for cases where you got the file from a Windows system? Also, with "checking", do you just mean "detect", or "convert such that it complies with what I need"?

Comment: In first step only checking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Detecting

- **UTF-8 encoding**: `file` will usually give you the encoding:

  ```
  file --brief --mime-encoding myfile.txt
  ```

  Note that it may either be 'us-ascii' or 'utf-8', depending on whether it finds some UTF-8 characters, so you'll need to accept both.

The following points will mostly require you to pipe the output into `wc -l` (to count the number of lines of the output) and check whether it's 0 or not. Alternatively, they should usually have a return value of 0 if they found something, or 1 if not (in which case your requirements are fulfilled):

- **No trailing white spaces**: That's a job for `grep`, I guess:

  ```
  grep -e '\s\+$' myfile.txt
  ```
- **Newline at the end of file**: If the last character according to `hexdump` or `xxd` is `0a`, there is a newline, and it's fine:

  ```
  xxd -ps myfile.txt | tail -n 1 | grep '0a$'
  ```

  (*note that, unlike for the other points denoted here, you want this to find something*)
- **No not-ascii chars**: This is the same as "UTF-8 encoding", except maybe a little more strict.

  If you *really* want to be sure there are only ASCII characters in a file (see @Anthon's answer), you'll probably need something like

  ```
  xxd -g1 myfile.txt | cut -c 10-56 | grep '[a-f89][a-f0-9]'
  ```

  This searches for any characters outside the ASCII range (0x00-0x7F). It's not very elegant, though.
- **LF for line endings**: `file` without any options will tell you something like

  ```
  ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
  ```

  For a script, probably something like the following could do:

  ```
  xxd -g1 myfile.txt | cut -c 10-56 | grep '0d'
  ```

### Fixing

- **UTF-8 encoding**: There is [`iconv (1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv). Essentially it takes a "from" encoding (`-f`), a "to" encoding (`-t`), and the file.
  The "to" encoding is probably `utf-8`, whereas the "from" encoding can be obtained using `file` as described at the top of my post:

  ```
  file_encoding="$(file --brief --mime-encoding myfile.txt)"
  iconv -f "$file_encoding" -t 'utf-8' myfile.txt
  ```
- **No trailing white spaces**: That's a job for `sed`, although I prefer the POSIX way (i.e. no `-i` switch) which means using `printf` + `ex`. Either way, the regex will look something like `s/\s\+$//g`. For the POSIX-compliant way:

  ```
  printf "%%s/\\s\\+\$//g\nwq\n" | ex -s myfile.txt
  ```

  For the non-POSIX-compliant way:

  ```
  sed -i 's/\s\+$//g' myfile.txt
  ```
- **Newline at the end of file**: Unix applications usually append a missing newline at the end of file when they save it. To exploit that, this is bit of a hack:

  ```
  printf "wq\n" | ex -s myfile.txt
  ```

  (*this will actually just open, save, quit*)
- **No not-ascii chars**: See "UTF-8 encoding" above.
- **LF for line endings**: There is [`dos2unix (1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix). It should do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the `file` command, it already does a good job of determining information about the contents, although it doesn't analyse the full data file.

If you have a large file `somefile` where the first utf-8 character doesn't appear until the end, `file somefile` will not detect that as an utf-8 file.