# How to use grep command in a file

Tags: linux, grep

I have a text file and I have several numbers inside that. Here are some sample numbers.

```
+-----------+
|NUMBER     |
+-----------+
| 75705310 |
| 75779034 |
| 75908237 |
| 75681768 |
```

I need to grep these numbers from another file in my remote server and the output should be as follows with the number and the count,

```
 1 75964761
 2 75964261
```

Here is my try, But this will not produce any results.

```
grep -f /data/session_1.log log_20221001 | sort | uniq -c
```

But when I use as below I could get the result, But I need to check whole list in session_1.log.

```
 grep -o '75964761' log_20221001 | sort | uniq -c
      1 75964761
```

Can someone help me on this issue..

Comment: [Check your files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/172320/108618) (especially `/data/session_1.log`) against Windows line endings (CRLF), trailing spaces and such.

Comment: Do you have those pipe characters before and after the number?  If so, deal with those (and @KamilMaciorowski 's suggestion) by piping your command through `awk '{print $2}'

Comment: also `grep -f file | sort | ...` can be reduced to `sort file | ...`

Comment: Your example output does not indicate pipe characters in the log file, as shown at the top of the question. Please [edit] your question to show the actual data. The formatting of the input is important if you want to get an answer that will work correctly for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per `grep`'s man page

```
grep -f /data/session_1.log log_20221001
```

uses this signature

```
grep [OPTION...] -f PATTERN_FILE ... [FILE...]
```

So `grep` obtains patterns from `/data/session_1.log`, one per line.  Since it's a log, I assume it has data instead of patterns.

Instead try this (I added the last line so you had some data that wasn't unique):

```
$ cat file
+-----------+
|NUMBER     |
+-----------+
| 75705310 |
| 75779034 |
| 75908237 |
| 75681768 |
| 75681768 |
$ sort file | uniq -c
      2 +-----------+
      2 | 75681768 |
      1 | 75705310 |
      1 | 75779034 |
      1 | 75908237 |
      1 |NUMBER     |
```

Comment: It's unclear what your answer suggests. Should the user just use `sort` and then `uniq -c`? What about the other file then?  If there's another file that contains the numbers that they want to investigate, surely the result of the `sort`+`uniq` pipeline needs to be filtered with this?